Fcm Flutter not handle message when iOS app is terminated
I am developing a flutter app using fcm and all notifications are working well.
I use data messages instead of notifications, to receive messages based on certain conditions.
but when ios app is terminated, it can't receive data message.
it works only when i reopened the app.
Android:

foreground - works well
background - works well
terminated - works well

iOS:

foreground - works well
background - works well
terminated - doesn't work

And FCM says:
On iOS, if the user swipes away the application from the app switcher, it must be manually reopened for background messages to start working again.
I think this is a unique problem with Fcm.
Is there any way to solve this?
If you have any good opinions please help me!
What I already have done:

Tested using real devices, not emulators.
Ran the app in release flutter run --release
Used (data payload + notification) message
Couldn't find a solution.for similar problems

This is BackgroundHandler
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {

  final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  final noticeNum = int.parse(message.data['noticeNum']);
  await loadButtonCheckedInfo();
  final switchButtonController = Get.put(SwitchButtonController());

  // Receive notifications only notification setting corresponding to noticeNum is true.
  if (switchButtonController.buttonCheckedList[noticeNum] == true) {    
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      message.data["title"],
      message.data["body"],

      // notifications details setting (Android, iOS)
      const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'high_importance_channel',              
          'high_importance_notification',         
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.max,
          color: Color(0xFF3043f2),      
        ),
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
          presentAlert: true,
          presentBadge: true,
          presentBanner: true,
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}


This is messaging server code
def sendToFcm(token, title, body, noticeNum):            
    
    # Send to one device
    if len(tokenList) == 1:
        message = messaging.Message(
            data = {
                'title': title,
                'body': body,
                'noticeNum': noticeNum
            },
            token = tokenList[0],
        )

    # Send to many devices
    else:
        message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
            data = {
                'title': title,
                'body': body,
                'noticeNum': noticeNum
            },
            tokens = tokenList,      
        )


This is not a unique problem with FCM. If the user swipes away the app, it will not receive silent notifications until the user relaunched it

Can you share the code in Flutter where you set FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage. And do you send the notification from cloud functions or from where you send it? If you send from cloud functions, also post the code how the getMessaging().sendEachForMulticast... part looks like if you have special configurations.

Thanks your comment! But most apps receive notifications even when user swipes away, terminated. and I'm curious how to do this. Is there no way for fcm?

Your code looks correct. I do the same thing as you in one of my apps where I just send data and then create a message with FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin. I have no clue why in Firebase stand it should not work when you "swipe the app away" cuz in my app everything works fine by my users and I also just test it and the notifications are still sent (Tested on iPhone 7 and 10). Anyway, can you check in Xcode in the Signing & Capabilities part and then Background Modes if you have Background Fetch and Remote Notifications enabled? And have you uploaded your APNs authentication key?
